# How can I check if a connection uses ssl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm  coding a file exchange and some files shouldnt be downloaded without ssl. So I need to check if a connection is ssl encoded or not. Does this depend to the webserver or is there any method for all webservers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to check `request.ssl?` to determine this.

As far as I can tell this is essentially just testing against `request.proto` to see if it is `"https://"`.

Comment: +1 Indirectly it tests also against various environment variables like `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL` or `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SCHEME`, so `ssl?` is not that trivial as it might look like :)

Answer (score -2):

I suppose it depends on the server configuration, but you can check if your transactions are encoded or not with a sniffer. A good one is [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).